# Mvvm light messenger, communication between viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

In my `ViewmodelA` I want to open a new window in `ViewModelB`, so i used the messenger class, but the probleme is that i need to reference `ViewModelB` inside the `ViewModelA`, so that `ViewModelB` can listen to the messages.
here is my implementation
in ViewModelA:

```
 private void btnAddExecute()
 {  
    // I need to instanciate ViewModelB otherwise it wont work/listen
    ViewModelB vb= new ViewModelB();

    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("ShowWindow"));       
 }
```

in `ViewModelB` i listen to the broadcasted messages in it's constructor.

is there anyway to decouple `ViewmodelA` from `ViewmodelB` ?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to reference `ViewModelB`?  Are you expecting a result or something?

Comment: I just want to experiment with the messenger class, and send data between viewmodels

Comment: Because you registered the message handler in B's constrcutor, and handle it there, you need to have an instance of `ViewModelB` alive someplace to actually handle the message.  Typically that instance would be created someplace else as part of your application (Two windows for instance, trying to communicate with each other).

Comment: This seems like something you should be using the NavigationService for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly see where the coupling is occurring if you are using the messenger properly.  There is no need to reference `ViewModelB`

**Edit**

Here is a way to do it without reference to an instance `ViewModelB`.  It uses a singleton to register for messages and create `ViewModelB`s when it receives the notification message.  I haven't tested this, it is just an idea.  Make sure ViewModelBCreator is used at some point so that the static constructor is called.

```
public class ViewModelBCreator()
{
    private static ViewModelBCreator instance;
    static ViewModelBCreator() { instance = new ViewModelBCreator(); }
    private ViewModelBCreator()
    {
        Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, true, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }
    private static void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage notification)
    {
        var vm = ViewModelB();
        //Do stuff with the new ViewModelB
    }
}  

public class ViewModelB
{ 
    public ViewModelB()
    {
        //etc . . .
    }
}

public class ViewModelA
{
    public void OpenTheWindow()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("ShowWindow"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there would need to be an instance of `ViewModelB` alive someplace for the message to do anything. Presumably that's why he is creating one.  I think he's having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BradleyUffner You may be right.  I was assuming he was trying to communicate through two open views or something similar.
I guess ViewModelB could have a static constructor that registers for the message?  Seems like a strange scenario.

Comment: @BradleyUffner exactly, i thought my question was clear, lol. @MrZander that was my implementation but i need to create an instance of `ViewModelB` in `ViewModelA`, otherwise `ViewModelB` won't listen to anything

Comment: You don't *have* to.  You could create that instance someplace else.  But typically that other instance is created for a reason, to back a view, as a property of a a parent or child Vm, as part of a UserControl, etc.

Comment: someplace else, do you mean in the ViewModelLocator? can you please give me an exemple

Comment: Anywhere else really.  When your application starts up it could create 2 windows, each backed by a different view model.  They could then send messages to each other through the `Messenger` without have a reference to each other at all.

Comment: if possible, i want the reference to be created on demand. Is there any solution (like DI)

Comment: @ArhHokagi I updated my answer with an implementation that should fit your needs.  It is kind of a work-around though.  I would suggest if you are using this for navigation that you look for other avenues.